# How to overload child class methods in PHP, respecting OOP and SOLID principles, when method signature must change?

Tags: php, oop, solid-principles

How to overload child classes methods in PHP respecting OOP and SOLID principles, when method signature must change. There's some design pattern intended to this?

```
<?php

class Client extends People
{
    protected function fillData(ClientDTO $clientDTO)
    {
        parent::fillData($clientDTO);
        ...
    }
}

class People
{
    protected function fillData(PeopleDTO $peopleDTO)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class ClientDTO extends PeopleDTO
{
   protected $orders;
}

class PeopleDTO
{
   protected $name;
}

?>
```

Comment: If the method signature changes, then the child is not overloading the parent's method; it's creating a new method.

Comment: short answer: you can't, because what you want is a different class and not a specialized sub-type

Comment: A pattern here could be the [abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), but this is perhaps (most likely) overkill for what you would like to achieve. It's a bigger pattern and it's harder to grasp. It allows you to handle different families of classes which share the same interface (hence the abstract). Just commenting as you asked for a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry here about changing a method signature, because signatures are compatible in your particular case as long as `ClientDTO` is a subclass of `PeopleDTO`. You can pass `ClientDTO` instance to `People::fillData` and it will still work. So I would say, no worries from that point of view. 
But you should use interfaces in place of hardcoded class dependencies in your signatures. You can call it a Strategy pattern if you want. This way, you'll respect Open\Closed and Dependency Inversion principles, since your classes will depend on abstractions. Or at least you should use some base abstract class if you think that creating interfaces would be an overkill, or your entities are very domain-specific.

P.S. I assume that you've made a mistake in your code sample: `class ClientDTO` should be `class PeopleDTO`

Comment: Sure thing, I've made a mistake in your code sample: class ClientDTO should be class PeopleDTO